# Using classification method in regression: EasyEnsemble

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data

Specifically with the [EasyEnsembleClassifier](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) implemented for sklearn, is it possible to use this for a regression task, or is it solely meant to be used in classification?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The docs for this classifier do note use for regression (https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.ensemble.EasyEnsembleClassifier.html?highlight=easyensemble)

Comment: I don't think that makes much sense, since it is class imbalanced learning, and there are no classes in regression. It might not be what you are expecting.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy If there are no classes, then I assume the classifier would not try to balance the classes. After that step, I believe the classifier just creates a forest of AdaBoost classifiers. Perhaps what's expected is similar to a RandomForest with an AdaBoost base estimator?

Comment: Then there is literally no point of using this library, since then you can use sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor (which is an actual regression algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.ensemble.EasyEnsembleClassifier.html?highlight=easyensemble):

`decision_function(X)` returns `score: ndarray of shape (n_samples, k)` where "the columns correspond to the classes in sorted order, as they appear in the attribute classes_. **Regression** and binary classification are special cases with k == 1, otherwise k==n_classes."

`fit(X, y)`: "Build a Bagging ensemble of estimators from the training set (X, y)" where y is "the target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in **regression**)."

Based on the documentation it would seem as though this classifier can be used in a regression setting.